# Navigation Drawer click not triggering

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjXoh.png)As you can see I have added 6 item in navigation drawer but on clicking Logout it is not triggered. And sorry for bad code format. I'm new here.

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_log_out) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody") 
@Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_wallet:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_search:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about_us:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contact_us:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_log_out:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,LogIn.class);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is my XML file for menu item. The id are the same I declared in the XML file. Log out in action bar is working fine but it is not working in Navigation Drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_wallet"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp"
            android:title="EasyFare Wallet" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_search"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_directions_bus_black_24dp"
            android:title="Search Bus" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_folder_shared_black_24dp"
            android:title="About Us"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_contact_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
            android:title="Contact Us" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_log_out"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
            android:title="Log Out" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

activity file with DrawerLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add your menu XML file for this activity? And can you put a `Log` statement in your `R.id.nav_log_out` case? I'm fairly sure Zainab's answer is correct, but want to rule out one other possibility.

Comment: are you sure you add nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)  in your code?

Comment: @VinayakB Ya Sure.

Comment: @Michael Dodd I have added my XML file for the activity

Comment: Please post your `Activity`'s layout, the one with the `<DrawerLayout>`.

Comment: @MikeM. I have added the XML file

Comment: Is that layout inside anything else? That is, is it included in another layout, or is it the one you're calling `setContentView()` with?

Comment: @MikeM. No it is not included in another layout.

Comment: When you click a menu item, do you see any visual feedback? That is, does it look like it gets clicked?

Comment: @MikeM. I'm not getting any visual feedback. But I do get a sound when the item is clicked.

Comment: Well, it really seems like something's covering the drawer. If you're sure there's no other layout involved, and you're not fiddling with `View`s in your code, and you're not transacting a `Fragment` over, then try cleaning/rebuilding your project. Another user recently had a similar issue with their drawer, and it was a glitch in the existing build.

Comment: @MikeM. Tried, didn't work for me. Anyways Thanks for helping.

Comment: We've listed about every possibility, here. You'll have to put together a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @MikeM. In Logcat it is showing inactivity, disconnecting from service on clicking Logout

Comment: That is apparently a Firebase thing, but it's not clear if it's directly caused by the `signOut()` call you have there. Also, the `startActivity()` right after that should either be starting your `LogIn` `Activity`, or crashing. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in that `case`? Or even replacing everything you have in that `case` with a log print, or a `Toast`, or some other simple indicator?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add brackets for case in logout..

```
case R.id.nav_log_out:
{
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,LogIn.class);
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Correct answer but wrong reason. OP needs brackets as he's declaring a new instance of an object (an `Intent` in this case). Multi-line switch statements are ok without brackets so long as nothing new is declared.

Comment: @ZainabJamil It didn't work in my case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AyushBherwani I'd say it's not reaching that case in the first place then. Please post the XML for your menu file and a log statement comparing the value of `id` to `R.id.nav_log_out`

Comment: You might have given some other id to your logout option in your option menu xml file then.. check that please. :)

Comment: And are you sure you are logging out from navigation view or you are using Action Bar Menu to log out ? @AyushBherwani

Comment: The Action Bar log out is working fine, but Navigation view log out is not working

Comment: Is it giving any error on FireBase signout line ? 
comment it for a sec and then run your app.

Answer (score 1):

Could you include the code in your activity's onCreate?

One possibility is that you forgot to register your activity as the listener for the navigation view.

```
mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on some other item, let's say the second one, gets this item triggered?

If yes add a break statement in your logout case and also create a default case.

You could also try replacing your code with the following sample.

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody") 
@Override public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_profile:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_wallet:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_search:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about_us:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contact_us:
            break;
        case R.id.nav_log_out:
            {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,LogIn.class);
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
            }
        DrawerLayout drawer;
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.THE_ID_OF_YOUR_DRAWER);  
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
   }

}
```

Also make sure that in your `OnCreate` , `OnStart` or `onResume` you include the following

```
 DrawerLayout drawer;

 drawer = findViewById(R.id.THE_ID_OF_YOUR_DRAWER);
```

Comment: Clicking on other item is not triggering the Logout case.

Comment: i meant if clicking `nav_wallet` triggers `nav_wallet` and so on. The most probable explanation is something is wrong with your tags as other users indicate.

Comment: I have DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) in onCreate.

Comment: Does your class extend `AppCompatActivity` and does it implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`?

Comment: Yes my class implements `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: Is your xml file for the drawer named `activity_main_drawer.xml`?

Comment: Yes I had created a Navigation Drawer activity

Comment: Could you remove the following lines of code from this file and tell me what happens?

`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
   `tools:showIn="navigation_view"`

Comment: Also does your project contain multiple resources? Meaning different layouts for portait and landscape orientation and for different screen sizes. If so make sure that all of these resource folders contain the same files and that you are not missing something there.

Comment: I removed the code, but nothing happened and I don't have multiple resources

Answer (score 0):

I will provide you with a code i use for a project of mine and try to see if you find any differences that would explain the fact your code does not work.

`AnnouncementsActivity.java`

```
    .
    .
    .
    .



public class AnnouncementsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {






    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_announcements);
            .
            .
            .
            .



                Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



                DrawerLayout drawer;

                drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_astiko);



                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();

                toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_toolbar);



                NavigationView navigationView =  findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

           .
           .
           .
           .



           }






        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.nav_first_item) {

                if(prev_activity_routes){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this,RoutesActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Direction Forth",bus_direction_forth);
                    intent.putExtra("Team",team);
                    intent.putExtra("Route name", value1);
                    intent.putExtra("odigos_onomateponimo",odigos_onomateponimo);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{

                    if(isAstiko){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TicketIssuanceActivityAstiko.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Direction Forth",bus_direction_forth);
                        intent.putExtra("Team",team);
                        intent.putExtra("Route name", value1);
                        intent.putExtra("odigos_onomateponimo",odigos_onomateponimo);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TicketIssuanceActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Direction Forth",bus_direction_forth);
                        intent.putExtra("Team",team);
                        intent.putExtra("Route name", value1);
                        intent.putExtra("odigos_onomateponimo",odigos_onomateponimo);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_item) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,DefinedTicketsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Direction Forth",bus_direction_forth);
                intent.putExtra("Team",team);
                intent.putExtra("Route name", value1);
                intent.putExtra("odigos_onomateponimo",odigos_onomateponimo);
                intent.putExtra("PreviousActivityRoutes",prev_activity_routes);
                intent.putExtra("isAstiko",isAstiko);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            .
            .
            .
            .


            }else if (id == R.id.nav_eighth_item) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer;         
            drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);        
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }





}
```

`ActivityAnnouncements.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_announcements"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/my_nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/my_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`app_bar_announcements.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.e_analysis.AlphaPro.MobileTicketing.AnnouncementsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_announcements" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`content_announcements.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:gravity="fill"
    tools:context="com.e_analysis.AlphaPro.MobileTicketing.AnnouncementsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_announcements">


    .
    .
    .
    .



</LinearLayout>
```

`my_drawer.xml` in the menu subfolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_first_item"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_printer_black"
                android:title="@string/nav_first_item_value"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_second_item"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_tune_vertical"
                android:title="@string/nav_second_item_value" />

            .
            .
            .
            .

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_eighth_item"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_logout"
                android:title="@string/nav_eighth_item_value" />
        </group>


</menu>
```

`my_nav_header.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    .
    .
    .
    .

</LinearLayout>
```

This code is working (not as it is ofcourse) so try to do some cross-checking with it and see what you are missing. Most probably it will be something easy to overlook and frustrating when you find out. Good luck!

Comment: @AyushBherwani Did you have any luck fixing your problem friend?